# Kim Kardashian Hollywood app game

Tags: kim-kardashian-hollywood

So I have two different Kim K games. One is on my iPad, and one is on my phone.  My iPad character had 116 k-stars in the account, so I had him gift the one on my iPhone.  It took his K stars.  He only has 20-some left but I can't find it on my phone.  I looked at the clothes in my closet and I never got a notification.  What do I need to do?